# Sequelize + NestJS: full outer join

Tags: postgresql, model, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

Is there a way to return data from db with a condition on a nested object and if the nested object is not present, return the parent anyway?

I have two models Mission and Request:

```
export class Mission extends Model<Mission> {
...
@HasMany(() => RequestEntity)
  requests: RequestEntity[];
...
}
```

```
export class Request extends Model<Request>{
...
  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
  })
  status: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => Mission)
  @Column(DataType.UUID)
  missionId: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column(DataType.UUID)
  userId: string;
...
}
```

So the relation between Mission and the Requests is one-to-many (mission can have more than one request). My goal is to filter the missions in the following way:

- if the mission has no request associated (so no row in the Request table is present with that given missionId), return the mission
- if the mission has one request for a given userId and the status 'pending', return the mission.

I tried looking at the documentation (Eager Loading - Sequelize),  but I don't find the solution. I am now trying this:

```
    const query: any = {
        limit: payload.limit,
        offset: payload.offset,
        order: [[payload.column, payload.direction]],
        where: {
          status: "open"
        },
        include: [{
          model: RequestEntity,
          where: { userId: user.id, status: 'pending' },
          required: false,
        }],
        transaction,
      };
```

I tried using `required: false`, however the result is that if the request is not pending or without the given userId, it does return the mission, just without the nested request. On the other hand, if I do not write `required: false` (by default it is `required: true`), all the missions without a requests are not returned.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use 2 sub-queries in `where` conditions in order to filter the parent table mainly because you wish 2 conditions on the same child table and also you use a paging.

```js
const query: any = {
        limit: payload.limit,
        offset: payload.offset,
        order: [[payload.column, payload.direction]],
        where: {
          status: "open",
          [Op.or]: [
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Request" where "Request"."missionId"="Mission".id)'), '=', '0'),
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal(`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Request" where "Request"."missionId"="Mission".id and "Request"."userId"=$userId and "Request".status='pending')`), '>', '0')
          ]
        },
        include: [{
          model: RequestEntity,
          where: { userId: user.id, status: 'pending' },
          required: false,
        }],
        bind: {
          userId: user.id
        },
        transaction,
      };
```

Comment: Hi Anatoly, thank you. Your solution does not work, the filters are not applied. I can see campaigns with status different from pending...

Comment: If you need to get messions that have only pending requests then you need to change the second `Sequelize.where` to Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal(`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Request" where "Request"."missionId"="Mission".id and "Request"."userId"=$userId and "Request".status<>'pending')`), '=', '0')

Comment: Still not working...My where is on id with Op.or:

- Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Requests" JOIN "Missions" ON "Requests"."missionId" = "Missions"."id")'), '=', '0'),

- Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal(`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Requests" JOIN "Missions" ON "Requests"."missionId" = "Mission"."id" where "Requests"."userId"='${user.id}' AND "Requests".status<>'pending')`), '>', '0')

But I still see the status "selected" for example in the output.

Comment: Because you indicated `>` instead of `=`

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. Not working even with ‘=‘

Comment: Could you update the post with the latest subqueries and `include` option?